# Suddenly lost sudo rights

Tags: linux, sudo

I have been using this installation (of Arch Linux) for a few years now, and have used `sudo` quite a lot. But suddenly it stopped working and I get the standard error message that the user is not in the `sudoers` file and this incident will be reported. So by using `su` and entering the root password I used `visudo` as root. There is a line `%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL`, and I confirmed that my user was in the `sudo` group.

I ended up fixing it by adding a line specifically for my user: `myname ALL=(ALL) ALL`, so I got it working that way, but it still seems to me that something is not quite right for this line to be even needed. Especially because it stopped working all of a sudden and I can't remember having changed this file since the initial installation over a year ago.

How could it be that it suddenly stopped working? Bad update? Hacked?

How do I get it working again that just being in the `sudo` group is enough? I have a line `%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL`, visudo reports no errors, my user is in group `sudo` but I still get `myname is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.` unless I add `myname ALL=(ALL) ALL`.

This was on a personal computer that should have no other users than me.

Comment: Did you get removed from the right group?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm in the `sudo` group, and the `sudo` group gets permissions in my `sudoers` file. I'm have not been removed from any group as far as I know.

Comment: Okay, that's what I meant. If you *had* been removed from that group, then it would not (even) be a change to the sudoers file.